# My code is not returning the correct height of the binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

Hi I recently coded up a code in c to find the height of a BST.
I just began to learn Data structures in C so I might have misconceptions lying around but in a nutshell, I have made a BST of height 3 but my code keeps saying it is 2. The insert code was mainly from a website and I don't think that part is a problem.
When I insert return 0 for the terminating condition in the finding height function it works out as 3 for the height but most of the websites write return 0;
Could anyone tell me where the problem lies?
Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
 #define max(a,b) \
   ({ __typeof__ (a) _a = (a); \
       __typeof__ (b) _b = (b); \
     _a > _b ? _a : _b; })

// Defining a single node for a tree

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
};

// Inserting a node into a Binary Search Tree (BST)

struct Node* insert(struct Node** root, int data)
{
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    temp -> data = data;
    temp -> left = NULL;
    temp -> right = NULL;

    // when tree is empty

    if ((*root)==NULL){ // Will always reach this if statement
        *root = temp;
        return *root;
    }
    else if (data <= (*root)->data){
        (*root)->left = insert(&((*root)->left), data);
    }
    else {
        (*root)->right = insert(&((*root)->right), data);
    }
}

// Finding height of binary tree

int FindHeight(struct Node* root)
{
    if (root == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    return max(FindHeight(root->left), FindHeight(root->right))+1;
}

int main()
{
    struct Node* root = NULL;
    insert(&root, 50);
    insert(&root, 30);
    insert(&root, 20);
    insert(&root, 40);
    insert(&root, 70);
    insert(&root, 60);
    insert(&root, 80);

/*            50
           /     \
          30      70
         /  \    /  \
       20   40  60   80 */

    printf("The height of this BST is %d\n", FindHeight(root));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assign the results of the `FindHeight` recursive calls to temporary variable, and use them in the invocation of the `max` macro. That will make it much easier to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)  your code. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code while monitoring variables.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code. Height is generally defined as the number of edges from root to its deepest leaf, so this works out.

Comment: I also suggest you use pen and paper to write down the value of variables to keep track of them, and to "draw" the tree as you construct it (with extra labels for the pointers/links). Then when you step through the `FindHeight` function you can compare the pointers to what you have written down.

Comment: You create a node in `insert()`, then you recursively call insert and create another node for the same data... Of course there are going to be problems... Creating a node and inserting it are two separate operations... Add a routine to traverse the tree and print out values in ascending order... Your inserts are messing up your inserts...

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying @Fe2O3. I'm going to go and fix that and see if it fixes my code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: AND... By definition, no two nodes have the same value. The condition `>=` is wrong, just not 'triggered' by your test data. If the data matches any node's data you have to reject the insertion... That is the definition of a BST. All subtrees of any node hold either values less (left) or greater (right) than the current node... Add some (left justified) print statements to trace the flow of the logic showing data and comparison results. You can remove them later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was with my insert function as suggested by @Fe2O3. When I rewrote the insert function as such
struct Node* insert(struct Node** root, int data)

```
{
    // when tree is empty

    if ((*root)==NULL){ // Will always reach this if statement
        *root = newNode(data);
        return *root;
    }
    else if (data <= (*root)->data){
        (*root)->left = insert(&((*root)->left), data);
    }
    else {
        (*root)->right = insert(&((*root)->right), data);
    }

    return *root;
}
```

it all worked out.

Thank you!

Comment: Glad you solved it! `:-)`... Please, though... In this code snippet, consider what happens when the first condition is true... `return` happens... The next `else` is superfluous... It's just more text that has no meaning. (I mean only the token `else`, not the `if` that follows..) `return` changes the execution point. Please either get rid of the first `else`, or keep it and get ride of the early `return` and use the one at the bottom of the function...